# Mass import and loading of images in React with react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-three-fiber

I am currently trying to import and use ~300 images (.png files) in my react project. They should be displayed inside a 3D view and loaded using the loader of react-three-fiber.

I have therefore copied the files to a folder named `images` and created a file `index.js` which exports the images as follows:

```
export { default as image_0 } from './0.png';
export { default as image_1 } from './1.png';
[...]
```

I previously also tried to export the images like this:

```
import image_0 from './0.png';
import image_1 from './1.png'
[...]

export { 
    image_0,
    image_1,
    [...]
}
```

The images are then loaded in another file:

```
import * as imageArray from "../../../assets/textures/images"

try {
    texture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, imageArray['sign_' + imageNumber]);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Image for number " + imageNumber + " not found.");
}
```

When testing this workflow without the try/catch I always get the following error inside the developer tools console:

`Uncaught Could not load undefined: undefined`

I have double checked that the corresponding images are present in `images` and that there is no naming error. After that I also tried to set all textures to one file which has been declared missing but was definitely inside the folder and therefore loadable:

```
texture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, imageArray['sign_x']);
```

I again got the same error and the image could not be loaded.

My guess is that this is a problem caused by too many imported images but I could not find any other solution to import such a high number of files in a project. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the issue is the large imports. I think (Im not certain) that its an import vs require thing. In the docs for `expo-three` they are using require. I also notice that for images require return an id rather than the files themselves, which may be key to solving your issue.

Here's a [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/lu9ZTgNDH) where I use require to get 130 images, load them with ExpoTHREE.TextureLoader, and then provide them as optional textures  for a threejs cube:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  useWindowDimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import { TextureLoader, loadAsync, THREE } from 'expo-three';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import ThreeWrapper from './components/ThreeWrapper';
import SafeAreaView from './components/SafeAreaView'
import imageArray from './assets/images/index';

global.THREE = global.THREE || THREE;


export default function App({ onComplete, ...props }) {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0.0);
  const [textures, setTextures] = useState([]);
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();

  const loadTextures = async () => {
    const values = Object.entries(imageArray);
    const total = values.length;
    const imgs = await Promise.all(
      values.map(async ([currentKey, requiredId]) => {
        try {
          let [{ uri, localUri }] = await Asset.loadAsync(requiredId);
          const url = Platform.OS == 'android'
            // android needs this?
            ? uri
            :localUri
          const texture = new TextureLoader().load(url);
          setProgress((prev) => prev + 1 / total);
          return texture;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
    );
    setTextures(imgs);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadTextures();
  }, []);
  if (Math.round(progress * 1000) / 1000 < 1)
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 38, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Loading...</Text>
        <Progress.Bar
          progress={progress}
          width={width * 0.8}
          height={36}
          borderRadius={50}
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: '300',
            textAlign: 'center',
            width: '100%',
          }}>
          {(progress * 100).toFixed(2) + '%'}
        </Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ThreeWrapper textures={textures} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/ipAAycJ_H